# Bash Command Substitution doesn't work

Tags: bash, script

This is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

thedate=$(date)


var='Current date is $thedate'

echo $var
```

The output is     Current date is $thedate  and I'd like to make it show the date,what did I do wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `bash` expands environment variables only once, unless you use `eval`, which causes the command line to be parsed twice:

```
eval echo $var
```

Note that the date and time displayed are those current when `thedate` is set, not when `$var` is referenced. To display the current time when `$var` is referenced, you need:-

```
var='Current date is $(date)'
eval echo $var
```

It would be better not to use variables, but define a function:-

```
cdate() { echo Current date is $(date); }
...
cdate
```

Of course, it is better still not to use `echo`, but let `date` itself add the extra text:

```
cdate() { date +"Current date is %c"; }
```

This doesn't output quite the same format as the `date` default, but there is no format specifier for the default.

Answer (score 1):

```
var='Current date is $thedate'
```

Variables don't expand within single quotes, so this assigns a string containing the literal text `$thedate`. You should use double quotes here to have the variable expand.

```
echo $var
```

Also, here, you should use double quotes around the variable to prevent it from being subject to word splitting and pathname expansion, i.e. `echo "$var"`. In this particular case you can mostly get away with not using quotes, since the date probably will not contain wildcard characters. But without quotes, e.g. the date string `Fri Dec  7 20:41:21 EET 2018` would output as `Fri Dec 7 20:41:21 EET 2018`, that is, the double space after the month name would be collapsed to a single space.

Comment: If you use `var="Current date is $thedate"`, then the date  and time are set at the time `var` is defined, not at the the time `$var` is referenced.

Comment: @AFH, at the time `thedate` is assigned (not `var`), since that's where the command substitution is. I don't know when exactly they want to run the `date` command, since they don't say, and there's the more immediate problem of not even expanding `$thedate`...

Comment: Sorry, you're quite right: I was writing my own answer at the time, and responded too quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Use double quotes instead of single quotes. Bash will not expand variables when in single quotes.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Please do not just copy answers (or parts) from the answers other people have posted on this question.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having other answers ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also [tour] for the site tour, and [help] for the help center.